# Railscast Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, railscasts

I just watched http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1 and after implementing my code, the form and everything else worked perfectly, except that when i create the form and go to the show page, it will add an integer instead of the chosen name

So for example in the form if i put

```
Category: Feline
```

on the show page it would put

Category: 1

If i put

```
Category: Example
```

on the show page it would put

Category: 2

Does anyone know why it shows this and how i could make it show the name i chose

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is incomplete. Check the code (he always upload the code to Github) https://github.com/railscasts/184-formtastic-part-1/blob/master/vet/app/views/animals/show.html.erb

So, instead of:

```
<p>
  <strong>Category:</strong>
  <%=h @animal.category_id %>
</p>
```

Put:

```
<p>
  <strong>Category:</strong>
  <%=h @animal.category.name %>
</p>
```

Use the association of ActiveRecord

Comment: How would i make the animal appear in the categories then

So for example on the animal form if i create an animal called Garfield and choose category= feline

If i go to /categories or /category how would i display on the index.html.erb that there is Garfield.

Show categories of an animal works but how to
show animals that belong to a category